# Finding sets that are $\mu^*$ measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $E=\{\emptyset, (-3, 2], \mathbb{R}\setminus (-3, 2], \mathbb{R}\}$ and $\rho:E\to [0, \infty]$ such that $\rho(\emptyset)=0$, $\rho((-3, 2])=4$, $\rho(\mathbb{R}\setminus (-3, 2])=\rho(\mathbb{R})=\infty$.
Consider the function $\mu^*:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\to [0, \infty]$, $$\mu^*(A)=\inf\left\lbrace\sum_{n=1}^\infty \rho(E_n)|(E_n)_{n\ge 1} \text{ such that } A\subset\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n\right\rbrace$$
I am asked to show that $\mu^*$ is an outer measure, to find $\mu^*(A)$ for $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ and to find the $\mu^*$ measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Showing that $\mu^*$ is an outer measure is really easy, the proof is essentialy the same as the one that the Lebesgue outer measure is an outer measure.

Consider now some set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ that is nonempty (it is clear that $\mu*(\emptyset)=0$) and is not $\mathbb{R}$ itself (it is also clear that $\mu^*(\mathbb{R})=\infty$, you can't cover $\mathbb{R}$ with $\emptyset$ and $(-3, 2]$ only). If $A\subset(-3, 2]$, then I believe that it is quite clear that $\mu^*(A)=4$ since any cover of $A$ with sets from $E$ must include $(-3, 2]$ and we can in fact choose this set to be the only member of the cover. If $A$ is not a subset of $(-3, 2]$, then we will have to include $\mathbb{R}\setminus(-3, 2]$ or $\mathbb{R}$ in the cover, so $\mu^*(A)=\infty$. We are now done with this part of the question.

As for the $\mu^*$ measurable sets, let's begin by noticing that $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are trivially $\mu^*$ measurable (this can be checked directly or by Carathedory's Theorem). Now I don't know how to continue because I am running into a lot of cases and I don't know how to handle them.